# Table normalization of given table

Tags: normalization, table

I've got a table and I'm supposed to figure out why it breaks with 1NF, 2NF and/or 3NF.
I know the differences between these three, but I'm bad at telling what attributes are primary keys and what is dependent on what. Can someone explain this in baby terms? I'm new to the whole database realm.

Here is the table:

```
Auditorium (title of the table)

ACodeID  NrSeats  Projector  PC  Uni  UniAdr  UniPhone
```

Explanation for each attribute:

`ACodeID` = Unique code for each auditorium.

`NrSeats` = Number of seats in the auditorium.

`Projector` = Whether or not the auditorium has a projector.

`PC` = Whether or not the auditorium has a computer.

`Uni` = Which university the auditorium is located in.

`UniAdr` = Address of the university.

`UniPhone` = The phone number for the university (each university only has one phone number in this example).

Also, any ideas as to how I can separate this table into separate ones so that the new tables fulfill 3NF?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a university table to which the auditorium table should refer rather than repeating the uni's data for each auditorium of that uni.